# pandas print to latex a dataframe returns an unexpected result

Tags: python, pandas, latex

I have a pandas dataframe

```
>>> ris
                   Pr Err    Tr Err    Pr Err    Tr Err    Pr Err    Tr Err
Data     nodes                                                             
boston   10      0.456532  0.458170  0.868836  0.810764  0.826163  0.775337
         30      0.512490  0.460417  0.623531  0.511936  0.600965  0.511689
         50      0.547000  0.447586  0.529250  0.377296  0.528913  0.398829
         100     0.781039  0.585664  0.452310  0.295945  0.480067  0.297470
         500     1.635246  1.084544  0.490629  0.188229  0.488209  0.174449
         1000    2.347967  1.325350  0.482844  0.153391  0.497174  0.139749
         5000    6.112860  3.248268  0.469981  0.141781  0.465061  0.055253
crime    10      0.713751  0.534806  0.959765  0.909708  0.964622  0.932691
         30      0.897192  0.648438  0.957707  0.814946  0.924469  0.835406
         50      1.259947  0.835315  0.958826  0.763053  0.935411  0.752043
         100     1.788571  1.188414  0.893760  0.675943  0.878403  0.638281
         500     3.705343  1.925542  0.875850  0.442439  0.917819  0.210832
         1000    5.364042  2.730365  0.877851  0.401714  0.834504  0.095997
         5000   11.592207  5.696515  0.924210  0.128621  0.757942  0.008422
diabetes 10      0.724064  0.708919  0.896751  0.884411  0.876967  0.871300
         30      0.776270  0.697421  0.748575  0.718090  0.770397  0.722314
         50      0.831268  0.738589  0.744160  0.670036  0.732472  0.681045
         100     0.944318  0.746765  0.725481  0.644612  0.739595  0.646943
         500     2.049824  1.295420  0.744597  0.638818  0.848764  0.342133
         1000    3.023125  1.945415  0.726805  0.632582  0.841408  0.202868
         5000    8.248108  4.950347  0.729375  0.614312  0.849506  0.049566
j2m      10      0.262522  0.220741  0.704471  0.707829  0.975908  0.971793
         30      0.329172  0.249799  0.612609  0.595846  0.937233  0.913272
         50      0.540852  0.392339  0.569175  0.550119  0.905082  0.870621
         100     0.837123  0.648585  0.537721  0.499987  0.846324  0.802037
         500     1.939758  1.398511  0.472884  0.354905  0.683411  0.496362
         1000    2.981468  2.151604  0.431983  0.307520  0.663899  0.339811
         5000    6.577426  4.737849  0.408002  0.290080  0.452132  0.022331
wine     10      0.821250  0.806193  0.940909  0.934531  0.940558  0.933438
         30      0.838295  0.817293  0.887308  0.862306  0.889729  0.876763
         50      0.897821  0.847260  0.872193  0.837761  0.872479  0.835796
         100     1.009768  0.909182  0.857645  0.814801  0.862258  0.809452
         500     1.675544  1.310232  0.855094  0.783809  0.940632  0.618788
         1000    2.094566  1.548781  0.863529  0.765906  0.973830  0.432291
         5000    5.004573  3.293214  0.861923  0.698045  0.920401  0.115565
>>>
```

and  I want to use this table in a latex documents. I want to print it exactly as it is but in latex format.

I try to print it with

`print(ris.to_latex(float_format= lambda x: str(np.round(x, 3))))`

and I get this result that is not my original dataframe.

```
>>> \begin{tabular}{llrrrrrr}
\toprule
       &      &  Pr Err &  Tr Err &  Pr Err &  Tr Err &  Pr Err &  Tr Err \\
\midrule
boston & 10   &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
crime & 30   &   0.457 &   0.458 &   0.869 &   0.811 &   0.826 &   0.775 \\
diabetes & 50   &   0.512 &    0.46 &   0.624 &   0.512 &   0.601 &   0.512 \\
j2m & 100  &   0.547 &   0.448 &   0.529 &   0.377 &   0.529 &   0.399 \\
wine & 500  &   0.781 &   0.586 &   0.452 &   0.296 &    0.48 &   0.297 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

>>>
```

how can I solve ?

EDIT:

with the command `print(ris.reset_index().to_latex(index=False))` I get:

```
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrrrr}
\toprule
     Data &  nodes &     Pr Err &    Tr Err &    Pr Err &    Tr Err &    Pr Err &    Tr Err \\
\midrule
   boston &     10 &   0.456532 &  0.458170 &  0.868836 &  0.810764 &  0.826163 &  0.775337 \\
   boston &     30 &   0.512490 &  0.460417 &  0.623531 &  0.511936 &  0.600965 &  0.511689 \\
   boston &     50 &   0.547000 &  0.447586 &  0.529250 &  0.377296 &  0.528913 &  0.398829 \\
   boston &    100 &   0.781039 &  0.585664 &  0.452310 &  0.295945 &  0.480067 &  0.297470 \\
   boston &    500 &   1.635246 &  1.084544 &  0.490629 &  0.188229 &  0.488209 &  0.174449 \\
   boston &   1000 &   2.347967 &  1.325350 &  0.482844 &  0.153391 &  0.497174 &  0.139749 \\
   boston &   5000 &   6.112860 &  3.248268 &  0.469981 &  0.141781 &  0.465061 &  0.055253 \\
    crime &     10 &   0.713751 &  0.534806 &  0.959765 &  0.909708 &  0.964622 &  0.932691 \\
    crime &     30 &   0.897192 &  0.648438 &  0.957707 &  0.814946 &  0.924469 &  0.835406 \\
    crime &     50 &   1.259947 &  0.835315 &  0.958826 &  0.763053 &  0.935411 &  0.752043 \\
    crime &    100 &   1.788571 &  1.188414 &  0.893760 &  0.675943 &  0.878403 &  0.638281 \\
    crime &    500 &   3.705343 &  1.925542 &  0.875850 &  0.442439 &  0.917819 &  0.210832 \\
    crime &   1000 &   5.364042 &  2.730365 &  0.877851 &  0.401714 &  0.834504 &  0.095997 \\
    crime &   5000 &  11.592207 &  5.696515 &  0.924210 &  0.128621 &  0.757942 &  0.008422 \\
 diabetes &     10 &   0.724064 &  0.708919 &  0.896751 &  0.884411 &  0.876967 &  0.871300 \\
 diabetes &     30 &   0.776270 &  0.697421 &  0.748575 &  0.718090 &  0.770397 &  0.722314 \\
 diabetes &     50 &   0.831268 &  0.738589 &  0.744160 &  0.670036 &  0.732472 &  0.681045 \\
 diabetes &    100 &   0.944318 &  0.746765 &  0.725481 &  0.644612 &  0.739595 &  0.646943 \\
 diabetes &    500 &   2.049824 &  1.295420 &  0.744597 &  0.638818 &  0.848764 &  0.342133 \\
 diabetes &   1000 &   3.023125 &  1.945415 &  0.726805 &  0.632582 &  0.841408 &  0.202868 \\
 diabetes &   5000 &   8.248108 &  4.950347 &  0.729375 &  0.614312 &  0.849506 &  0.049566 \\
      j2m &     10 &   0.262522 &  0.220741 &  0.704471 &  0.707829 &  0.975908 &  0.971793 \\
      j2m &     30 &   0.329172 &  0.249799 &  0.612609 &  0.595846 &  0.937233 &  0.913272 \\
      j2m &     50 &   0.540852 &  0.392339 &  0.569175 &  0.550119 &  0.905082 &  0.870621 \\
      j2m &    100 &   0.837123 &  0.648585 &  0.537721 &  0.499987 &  0.846324 &  0.802037 \\
      j2m &    500 &   1.939758 &  1.398511 &  0.472884 &  0.354905 &  0.683411 &  0.496362 \\
      j2m &   1000 &   2.981468 &  2.151604 &  0.431983 &  0.307520 &  0.663899 &  0.339811 \\
      j2m &   5000 &   6.577426 &  4.737849 &  0.408002 &  0.290080 &  0.452132 &  0.022331 \\
     wine &     10 &   0.821250 &  0.806193 &  0.940909 &  0.934531 &  0.940558 &  0.933438 \\
     wine &     30 &   0.838295 &  0.817293 &  0.887308 &  0.862306 &  0.889729 &  0.876763 \\
     wine &     50 &   0.897821 &  0.847260 &  0.872193 &  0.837761 &  0.872479 &  0.835796 \\
     wine &    100 &   1.009768 &  0.909182 &  0.857645 &  0.814801 &  0.862258 &  0.809452 \\
     wine &    500 &   1.675544 &  1.310232 &  0.855094 &  0.783809 &  0.940632 &  0.618788 \\
     wine &   1000 &   2.094566 &  1.548781 &  0.863529 &  0.765906 &  0.973830 &  0.432291 \\
     wine &   5000 &   5.004573 &  3.293214 &  0.861923 &  0.698045 &  0.920401 &  0.115565 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: The pandas version is `'0.15.1'`

Comment: I have updated to `0.16` but I still get the same error.

Comment: Can you reset the index and then convert to latex to see what that gives? (`ris.reset_index().to_latex(index=False)`)

Comment: I have edited the question. It works more or less. This results is fine for me

Comment: Apparently, there is an issue for this: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8336, and also PR pending to fix this: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/8784